# Create a pdf from a DataTable

Tags: flutter, pdf, datatable

I have a `DataTable` with many columns and rows. I want that the User can create a Pdf from that DataTable.
Is it possible to convert a Widget like my DataTable to a Pdf?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pdf](https://pub.dev/packages/pdf) package. You should provide a List of data, then create pdf. Based on my knowledge, Its not a direct way to convert DataTable to PDF. For example

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:pdf/widgets.dart' as pw;

final pdf = pw.Document();
pdf.addPage(
  MultiPage(
    build: (context) => [
      Table.fromTextArray(context: context, data: <List<String>>[
        <String>['Username', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Gender'],
        ...userList.map(
            (user) => [user.username, user.firstName, user.lastName, user.gender.toString()]).toList()
      ]),
    ],
  ),
);
```